# Custom fieldset Legend css

Tags: css, forms, legend, fieldset

How can i recreate the classic behavior of a form with fieldset and legend

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      Text
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

using a div and a label?

```html
<div>
  <label>
    Text
  </label>
</div>
```

I need the label to have a transparent background.

How can I recreate it in a custom way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a transparent background, most elements already do that by default.  It needs a white background and then just move it up to be on top of the line.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

label {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    Text
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I had arrived at this result with the white background. but I need it to be transparent because the underlying background can vary, for example it can be a background with gradients. that's why I was wondering if it was possible to make it transparent

Comment: Ah I see, you should have specified that in your question.  I suppose you could maybe hide the top border and then use `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to be positioned and use them to draw each half of that line... but that would be a real hack to do that.  Why not just use the `<legend>` element and use that default behavior?  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes, sorry maybe I wasn't clear. anyway i will try to do as you said. I can't use fieldset and legend because I need the label to be above the input field